# Swift 2.0, UITableView: Fetch index of 'checked' rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, uibutton, swift2

I have a UITableView in a UIViewController. I have a button at the bottom of this view controller. All the table cells contain a checkbox, which is a subclass of UIButton and a UILabel. When the button is pressed, I want to fetch the text of labels for all the 'checked' cells. Now I can't use cellForRowAtIndexPath because that returns a nil value for cells that are not visible. I therefore want to index my datasource. But the problem is, since UIButton does not have a UIButtonDelegate like UITextfield, I don't know how to capture the button clicks and store the indexPath rows for the cells for which the checkbox was checked. Please help! Thanks a lot!

This is my checkbox code, for reference

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/
// images
var checkedImage = UIImage(named: "check")
var unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "uncheck")

// bool property
var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if isChecked == true {
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        } else {
            self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender == self) {
        if isChecked == true {
            isChecked = false
        } else {
            isChecked = true
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you consider keeping these values in an array? It's simple solution, but maybe worth considering.

Comment: I have my values in an array, but I need an index to retrieve values from this array. This index will be the indexPath.row of the 'checked' row.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a tableviewcell. In that you have to create all elements in you cell. And in that cell class you have to maintain this variables
var indexofRow // Set this at the time of setting cell for UITableView .

```js
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
    let cell: yourFeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourTableCell") as!yourFeedCell
    cell.indexofRow = indexPath.row;

  }

  /*Code in you cell class*/
  //Maintain one dictonary Globally 
  var listOfCheckedCells = [Int: Bool]()
    // bool property



  var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet {
      if isChecked == true {
        self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        listOfCheckedCells[self.indexofRow] = true
      } else {
        self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        listOfCheckedCells[self.indexofRow] = false
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this will Help

Answer (score 0):

You have already subclassed from `UIButton`. AFAICS, you need a method call in order to be aware when the button is pressed. There is a method on [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/sendAction:to:forEvent:) (which is also applicable to `UIButton`):

```
func sendAction(_ action: Selector,
             to target: AnyObject?,
       forEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

> UIControl implements this method to forward an action message to the
>   singleton UIApplication object (in its
>   sendAction:to:fromSender:forEvent: method) for dispatching it to the
>   target or, if there is no specified target, to the first object in the
>   responder chain that is willing to handle it. Subclasses may override
>   this method to observe or modify action-forwarding behavior. The
>   implementation of sendActionsForControlEvents: might call this method
>   repeatedly, once for each specified control event.

You can override the method, call the super's implementation and let your observers/delegates know that the associated action is about to be performed.

Comment: This way is far more general than just reporting the state of your button within buttonClicked:

Comment: I did not understand this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Table view cells are populated only when they're visible so if you wanna save a value of a cell and keep it around even when its not visible, create a dictionary with the index path as key and the content of the cell as value. Then just update the dictionary when the check box is checked and unchecked. Finally when 'the button at the bottom of the view' is clicked fetch your data from the dictionary. here is somewhat a sample

```
var textOfLabels:[NSIndexPath:String]?

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let view = sender.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! UITableViewCell //or your custom cell name
    let indexPath = itemTable.indexPathForCell(cell)
    if (sender == self) {
        if isChecked == true {
            isChecked = false
            textOfLabels?.updateValue(theLableText, forKey: indexPath)
        } else {
            isChecked = true
            textOfLabels?.removeValueForKey(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```